# *NIX REGEXP number series

Tags: regex

Am playing around with regexp's but this is my headache. I have a dynamic number which needs a suffix. The suffix is always 0 to 9, 99 or 999.

**Example:**

I have the number `461200` and now I want to create an regexp that will match `461200` to `461209`. What I've learned it should be `^46120[0-9]$`? Is this correct or somewhere to the left of hell?

Ok, let us assume it is correct and I now want to match 461200 - 461299? This is where I get lost.

`^4612[0-9]{2}`?

It cannot be. I am yet to figure this out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1 digit at the end you need:

```
^4612[0-9]$
```

2 digits at the end:

```
^4612[0-9]{2}$
```

3 digits at the end:

```
^4612[0-9]{3}$
```

The number in braces `{}` means the number of time the preceding character or set has to be repeated.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `\d` as a slightly shorter notation for `[0-9]`.

Comment: To follow standard can I use ^4612[0-9]{1}$ aswell?

Comment: @user3218338 Yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

> Ok, let us assume it is correct and I now want to match 461200 -
>   461299?

You can either repeat the desired character class by saying `[0-9][0-9]` or use quantifiers `[0-9]{2}`.

It can be either:

```
^4612[0-9][0-9]$
```

or

```
^4612[0-9]{2}$
```

Both would work.

Comment: So 4610000 - 460999 should be ^4610[0-9][0-9][0-9]$ correct?

Comment: @user3218338 You can either repeat the class `[0-9]` or use quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this regex:

`^4612\d{2}$`